# how can I add an html to an element without id with javascript without jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html code:

```
    <div class="someclass">
        <ul>
           <li><a title="someFile" href="somefolder/somefile.pdf">File Name</a>
           <li><a title="someFile2" href="somefolder/somefile2.pdf">File 2</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I would like the link to become:

```
    <li><a title="someFile" href="somefolder/somefile.pdf" target="_blank">File Name</a>
    <li><a title="someFile2" href="somefolder/somefile2.pdf" target="_blank">File 2</a>
```

Can this to be done with pure javascript, without jquery or other libraries?

I have done similar things with jquery using getElementByID, but here element has no id, all that it has is the class "someclass" and for various reasons, I don't want to change the html. What I am trying to do is just to insert small javascript on the bottom of the page which will be executed when the document is loaded using the:

```
window.onload="myFunction()";
```

Can this task be accomplished on the way that I want to do it?

Comment: jQuery is written in Javascript. So everything jQuery can do, can be done with Javascript.

Comment: As i understand the difference only in _target_ attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var links = document.querySelector('.someclass').getElementsByTagName('a');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function(el) {
    // set attribute
    el.setAttribute('target','_blank');
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/krktmghd/ for working example

This answer is is IE9+ so yes you don't really need jQuery

Answer (score 4):

you just need to write

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    matches[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qpL134z9/4/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var pageLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var x in pageLinks) {
    pageLinks[x].target = "_blank";
}
```

Comment: This also worked, but the issue was to open ALL links in new window, the accepted answer opened just those that was inside in the specific class. Great job however.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var prnt = document.querySelector('.someclass ul').childNodes;
for(var i=0;i<prnt.length;i++){
    if(prnt[i].nodeType == 1){
       prnt[i].firstChild.setAttribute('target','_blank');        
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<div class="someclass">
    <ul>
       <li><a title="someFile" href="somefolder/somefile.pdf" target="_blank">File Name</a>
       <li><a title="someFile2" href="somefolder/somefile2.pdf" target="_blank">File 2</a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rgectngu/)

Answer (score -2):

Have a look here.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp

As indicated, this is what you can do with only Javascript

```
var para = document.createElement("p"); //create p element
var node = document.createTextNode("This is new."); //create text element
para.appendChild(node); //append text to p

var element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(para); //append p to somewhere in your page
```

Comment: please try to understand problem before answering